# WPF Get the Cursor in the box

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, cursor, radio-button

Hi all im having a Radio Button and Text box in front it,
once i check the button the text box will become visible!

But i also want to my Cursor be visible in a text box to so easier for user to type \
how i can do these?!

thats my function

```
   private void SelectQualityChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtSelectedQuantity.IsEnabled = true;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
        private void checkBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          textBox1.IsEnabled = true;
          textBox1.Focus();
        } 

        private void checkBox1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.IsEnabled = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this all in Xaml. No code behind is required.

First bind the `RadioButton` `IsChecked` property to the `TextBox` `IsEnabled` property, then use a `Trigger` on `TextBox` `IsEnabled` true to set the focus on the `TextBox` using the `FocusManager.FocusedElement` property.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton x:Name="radioBtn" Content="Click me!"  />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtbox" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=radioBtn, Path=IsChecked}">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=txtbox}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this. I think you should pass the boolean value after the check box click event

```
   private void SelectQualityChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtSelectedQuantity.IsEnabled = SelectQuality.Checked;
        txtSelectedQuantity.Focusable = SelectQuality.Checked;
        if(SelectQuality.Checked)
        {
            txtSelectedQuantity.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
private void radioButton1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
```